# Loop Just once on each HTML table row

Tags: jquery, html

I want to implement an Edit functionality on the table rows. So when the page is loaded I Get the value the user had selected and the get JSON for the rest of the drop-down values. If the value the user had selected is equal to any JSON value I skip it. The problem is My javascript is looping as many times as there are many HTML rows. How do I ensure that I only get JSON only Once and Still Skip the value the user had selected on each row?

Here is The Code I'm Using to Get the Json Values and Populate them on the DropDown Menu

```
var selectedAccount = $("#mytable tbody tr .type_selected"); //The Drop Down Element
selectedAccount.each(function() {                      
    valueselected = $(this).val();//Value User had Selected
    $.getJSON(url, function (data,e) {//Get Json
        $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
            if(entry.id == valueselected){
                return true; //Ski the Value No need of Diplaying It
            }
            dropdown.append($('<option id="itemId'+ entry.id+'"></option>').attr('value', entry.id).text(entry.name)); //append Here
                //alert(entry.No_);
            })                
        });
});
```

[image: This is What I'm getting. It's Looping Twice Because I have Two Rows]
 // dropdown.select2();

Comment: Kind of confused...there's a `<table>` and an empty `<select>`. When a `<tr>` is selected...then all of the data on a JSON is then appended to the `<select>` as `<option>`s **except** for the data that was selected on the `<tr>`?

Comment: It's Like this. My explanation is quite horrible. The user had filled in the values of the table rows on another page. What I'm trying to do is an Edit functionality which is on another page. For example, the user filled the form but never completed it and they have to continue with it the next day or something. So as the page loads, I get the values the  JSON Values, populate them on the drop-down and skip whatever the user had selected. The problem is the If the user had 3 rows filled, my code will get the JSON three times.  How do I ensure it Loads only once per row?

Comment: So each `<tr>` has a `<select>`?  When `<option>`s are created, their values are derived from a JSON? If so then generate a new JSON that stores what the user has previously selected.